# why is my script looping without finishing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

when i run this on the website https://www.nike.com/experiences it does not stop opening tabs however unless i missed something it shouldn't loop much more than twice because of these infos returns integer 4:

```js
dispo = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5].querySelectorAll('a').length
```

```js
var checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
    
    if (document.documentElement.innerText.includes('Paris') == true){
        dispo = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5].querySelectorAll('a').length

        for (i=0; i<dispo+1;i += 2){
            window.open(document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5].querySelectorAll('a')[i].href,"_blank")
        }
        clearInterval(checkInterval )
    };
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Well it is scary you are using a global variable `i` and global `dispo`

Comment: Because `checkInterval` isn't defined when you create the function inside of the `setInterval`

Comment: Your code is also inefficient since you keep looking up the same things over and over again.  `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5].querySelectorAll('a'); var disp = elems.length; for(var i=0; i<dispo; i+=2){ console.log(elems[i].href)}`

Comment: @Samathingamajig, that is not correct....

Comment: hello, i still don't understand why, even if my code is not that beautiful i can't see why it is looping without finishing but i clear at one time the interval. Also i want it to be as fast possible so that's why im using interval method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `document.querySelectorAll('.grid')[5].querySelectorAll('a')[i]` is undefined, that `undefined.href` throw an exception, so it failed to execute clearInterval.

Comment: when `dispo = 2`, and `i<dispo+1; i += 2`,  the `i` could be 2, out of index.